# phpmyadmin column headers move in table when you scroll

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have noticed that when you scroll through a page in PHPMYADMIN the column headers shift sometimes putting the column header over the top of a different column causing confusing but i cannot for the life of me work out where to report this bug.

Anyone know?

Comment: can you post a screengrab?

Comment: @durbnpoisn I sure can, this problem is also prevalent in this bug report http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/3935/ opened last year, except i get the same problem in google chrome.

Comment: here is the image link. http://b2b.resource-ps.co.uk/phpmyadmin/phpmabug.jpg

Comment: It appears that something is cross-wired for sure.  Are you positive that something in your data isn't causing the rendered text to break the table set?  Have you looked at the rendered code to see what it looks like?

Comment: @durbnpoisn it happens in every table, in every browser and has done for many versions of PHPmyadmin!

Comment: That's why I'm suggesting that it may have something to do with your data.  What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: @durbnpoisn This question is now answered. Turns out it is a bug in the coding of PMA not my data (which is just a stack of simple text and strings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open <php_my_admin_folder>/js/sql.js and change
`return $originalColumns.eq(i).width();`
to 
`return Math.floor($originalColumns.eq(i).width()) + 1;`
tested in pma 4.2.6+ and should work in prev releases.

Comment: This is the correct solution and is the fix to the bug! Thank you fpr this! Hopefully this bug will be fixed on all other versions of PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been reported and fixed for version 4.2.9; see https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4538 for details.